# Dockerfile failing to replicate the steps

Tags: linux, docker, proxy, iptables

i followed certain steps to get `curl 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json'` to show the proxy IP using `redsocks` and `iptables` but when i try to containerize it by replicating the steps, it fails in the part where i apply iptables rules in entrypoint.sh telling me `i dont have permission to do so` and curl gives me the system ip, how can i containerize it (there is a particular reason i am not setting environment variable proxy, hence redsocks and iptables are a must)

My Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest 
RUN apt update 
RUN apt-get install -qy redsocks 
RUN apt-get install -qy iptables 
RUN apt-get install -qy iptables-persistent 
RUN apt install curl -qy
RUN apt-get install sudo -qy
COPY . /code 
RUN rm -f /etc/redsocks.conf 
RUN ln -s /code/redsocks.conf /etc/redsocks.conf 
RUN cp /code/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh 
USER root

ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
echo "Restarting redsocks and redirecting traffic via iptables"
/etc/init.d/redsocks restart
iptables -t nat -N REDSOCKS
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 0.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 240.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN

iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 12345
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 12345
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -p tcp --dport 11371 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 12345

iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j REDSOCKS

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 11371 -j REDSOCKS
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDSOCKS
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDSOCKS

echo "Check IP: "

curl 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json'
echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------"
exit
```

Comment: Generally you wouldn't do anything like this: Docker fully manages the network environment for your container, and you're generally prohibited from running `iptables` and other network-management commands.  A container also runs a single process, and you don't generally use init scripts or other things to launch system daemons.  The setup you show might be more suited to a full virtual machine than a lightweight container.

Comment: my plan was to have multiple containers with multiple proxies(which i provide in redsocks) so i wanted to do this, security is not of concern to me right now so, is that possible?

Answer (score -1):

Answer was simple, just had to `docker run --privileged <image>`